# Elasticsearch: Use regex to search the text containing dash or minus sign

Tags: elasticsearch

We have Elasticsearch 6.5. I am using it to search a index using regex and it is working for most of the case.

```
{
  "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": { "field1:field2" : "Complete" }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "regexp": { "field1.field3" : ".*mysource_.+20190102" }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size":10000
}
```

Using the above query is running fine for most of the cases. For e.g. mysource_121_AB_PQ_20190102 (and similar) are fetched correctly.
However, I have a text stored as mysource_101_XY-FG_20190102, which is not fetched using the above regex.

If I do not use regex, simple match fetches the data correctly. Only this regex is not working on it. I believe it is due to the hyphen or dash or minus (-) sign.

Can someone help in searching such data using the regex?

Please note the index is not maintained by us, so I cannot run admin commands on index.

Comment: Can you change your index mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case your field has a sub field with `keyword` type in it use (field1.field3.keyword):

```
{
"query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": { "field1:field2" : "Complete" }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "regexp": { "field1.field3.keyword" : ".*mysource_.+20190102" }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size":10000
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, using keyword helped me.

Comment: great , can you point to any documentation to understand why this works?